# Suggestion for Maintaining a Set of Similar Objects

Tags: java

I have a class say Continent. I create many such instances of it. I want to store all such instances in a Set. Every time a new object is created, it should be added to the Set.

```
public class Continent {

    private static HashSet<Continent> globalContinents = new HashSet();
    final private String continent_name;

    Continent(String continent_name){
        this.continent_name = continent_name;
        Continent.globalContinents.add(this);
    }
}
```

This is giving me a warning of leaking object. I'm going to use multithreading so, do you have any suggestions to implement such a thing effectively ? a design idea ?

Comment: First off, if that's your entire Continent class then you'll want to implement equals and hashCode to satisfy the contract for a Set (e.g. delegate to your continent_name)

Comment: One thing ive thought of is using a static method to create the object, and add it to the set. this solution sounds fair ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple factory for your Continents.

```
public class ContinentFactory {
    private Set<Continent> continents = new HashSet<>();

    public Continent create(String name) {
        Continent continent = new Continent(name);
        continents.add(continent);
        return continent;
    }

    public static class Continent {
        private String continentName;

        public Continent(String continentName) {
            this.continentName = continentName;
        }

        ...
        equals and hashcode 
        ....
    }
}
```

You should follow Java naming conventions too:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, any good resource to learn more about this 'Factory' design ?

Comment: This is just an abstraction over creating a Continent. But I recommend this repository if you want to have explore numerous patterns implemented in java - https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Mabye is is easier to implement Continent as an inner class:

```
public class Earth {

    private static HashSet<Continent> globalContinents = new HashSet();

    public Earth() {

    }

    public void addContinent(String name) {
        globalContinents.add(new Continent(name));
    }

    private class Continent {

        private String continent_name;

        public Continent(String continent_name){
           this.continent_name = continent_name;

        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.continent_name;
        }
    }

}
```

So, all coninents are in a HashSet of Earth, so you need just to create one Object of Earth and then add Coninents with addContinent().